# is there a way to graph the imports within a Python module?

Tags: python, python-import, graph-visualization

I'm trying to understand the structure of a medium-sized Python project (10ksloc) while planning at refactor. Are there any utilities that have at least the following feature:

- Running said utility generates a graph of just the module-level import relationships

Additional features that would be nice to have:

- explanation of where an import relationship comes from (eg "imported a.SomeClass at b.py:2")
- filtering out modules from standard library
- filtering out modules installed to site-packages
- some level of interactivity, like with `flamegraph.pl`'s SVG output
- exporting to DOT format for further visualization opportunities

I understand that this functionality must exist for projects like `pyinstaller` to work under the hood (how else would you do hook discovery?), but haven't seen anything from my searches.

If there's nothing like this, how would you build such a feature with the last module?

Comment: I googled it just now and found https://github.com/thebjorn/pydeps